# I got "Undefined name 'user'." this error while submitting the submit button

Tags: json, flutter, spring-boot, http

- - `Text.rich(
- TextSpan(
- text: 'Already have an account? ',
- style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFB5B1B1)),
- children: [
- TextSpan(
- text: 'Login',
- style: const TextStyle(
- color: Color(0xFF0990F2),
- fontSize: 14,
- fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
- recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
- - ```
                            ..onTap = () {
    ```
- createUser(user);//error occurred here    Undefined name 'user'.
- - ```
                            },
    ```
- - ```
                        ),
    ```
- 
- - ```
                      ],
    ```
- - ```
                    ),
    ```
- - ```
                  )
    ```
- 
- - //post request
- Future createUser(User user) async {
- final response = await http.post(
- Uri.parse('https://queryus-production.up.railway.app/user/register'),
- headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
- body: jsonEncode({
- - ```
          'firstName': user.firstName,
    ```
- - ```
          'lastName': user.lastName,
    ```
- - ```
          'middleName': user.middleName,
    ```
- - ```
          'email': user.email,
    ```
- - ```
          'password': user.password,
    ```
- - ```
          'confirmPassword': user.confirmPassword
    ```
- - ```
        }));
    ```
- print(response.body);
- 
- if (response.statusCode == 201) {
- return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
- else {
- throw Exception('Failed to create user.');
- - ```
    }
    ```
- - }
- 
- 
- 
- I want to fix the error and I am expecting that I can find the solution here`

Comment: Hi Ashish, please format your question, it's difficult to read this. So, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an instance the of `User` model and then pass reference to the function in the click function.

Like this:

```
// Create the instance of User model.
final user = User();

// Pass the instance into the function.
createUser(user);
```